# Is there any experimental proof for QED theory?

Tags: experimental-physics, quantum-electrodynamics

Are there any primary experiments used to try to prove the Quantum Electrodynamics theory? Were they all successful, and how were they performed? Also, I was wondering where Feynman's equations are used primarily now, everyday.

Comment: You can test QED using high power lasers. [ELI-NP](http://www.eli-np.ro/scientific-papers/Strong_field_physics_and_QED_experiments.pdf) will have an experimental program dedicated to test QED features.

Comment: You may want to split this into 2 questions. Additionally, a question like "Where are Feynman's equations used now?" is way too broad for physics SE.

Comment: The equations behind Feynman diagrams are mostly used in Particle Physics. They are experimentally tested in particle accelerators (like LHC).

Comment: As far as I know, ESR (Electron Spin Resonance) gives the best comparison of the theory with experiment.

Comment: Experiments with multiple generations of accelerators have all proven QED. The deviation of the electron and muon g-factor from its Dirac value of 2 is perhaps the most accurate confirmations. Also check out the Lamb shift.

Answer (score 1):

Measuring the [fine structure constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-structure_constant#Measurement) was a great validation of quantum electrodynamics.

The experiment is still [being refined](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/360/6385/191.full)"

> Refining the fine-structure constant
>
> The fine-structure constant, α, is a dimensionless constant that characterizes the strength of the electromagnetic interaction between charged elementary particles. Related by four fundamental constants, a precise determination of α allows for a test of the Standard Model of particle physics. Parker et al. used matter-wave interferometry with a cloud of cesium atoms to make the most accurate measurement of α to date. Determining the value of α to an accuracy of better than 1 part per billion provides an independent method for testing the accuracy of quantum electrodynamics and the Standard Model. It may also enable searches of the so-called “dark sector” for explanations of dark matter.

Comment: But QED does not predict a number for alpha. I would rather say that the anomalous  g-factor of the electron and the muon are very sensitive tests.

Comment: @Pieter The point is that if you measure $\alpha$ in different ways, QED predicts you'll get the same result. (This is just like how Newtonian mechanics predicts that measuring $F/a$ and $F_g / (GM/r^2)$ will give the same result.)